# Get the Row ID dynamically in the query

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

Suppose if I have 4 rows in the gridview and I want to delete only second row so how to get the dynamic ID from the table so that I can delete that particular row with unique ID

Here is my query, but I am not able to bring the respective ID:-

```
protected void GrdTraining_DeleteCommand(object sender, Obout.Grid.GridRecordEventArgs e)
{
    if (Session["dt10"] != null)
    {
        dt10 = (DataTable)Session["dt10"];
    }
    else
    {
        BindDatatable();
    }
    DataRow[] grdTrain = dt10.Select("SR_NO=" + Convert.ToString(e.Record["SR_NO"]));
    dt10.Rows.Remove(grdTrain[0]);
    AddToViewState("GrdTraining");
    CF.ExecuteDT("DELETE FROM EMP_ATTACHED_DOCUMENTS where mkey="+ );  // mkey is my unique column in the table, how to get the ID here for the row which I want to delete ?? 
}
```

Please suggest

Comment: You mean everytime you delete a row on the datagrid, it also deletes that record in database by ID? `CF.ExecuteDT("DEL..")` is used to delete in db?

Comment: @QuanNguyen: yes exactly that's what I want. **EDIT**. yes that query is for that only

Comment: If so, why you don't use `e.Record["SR_NO"]` in your DELETE command?

Comment: @QuanNguyen:. `e.Record["SR_NO"]` is for grid and my table name is different. Also, `SR_NO` is not in my table

Comment: @QuanNguyen: can you help me with this ?? let me know if you have any doubt

Comment: Let me confirm again, `SR_NO` is different with `mkey` in the table `EMP_ATTACHED_DOCUMENT`?

Comment: @QuanNguyen: YEs, `SR_NO` is for the gridview row. But `mkey` is the `ID` which is getting stored in the database. So I want `mkey` as unique to delete the row

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87633/discussion-between-quan-nguyen-and-nadeem).

Comment: Is mkey column is present in the gridview?

Comment: @SankarRaj: No, it is in the table where the data gets saved

Comment: Then how can we delete it? Just get identity column into the Grid view. If you want to hide it make it visible="false". Then pass that value while delete. Like e.record["mkey"] in where condition. Hopes it will helps.

Comment: @SankarRaj: yes i know that, but the thing which I want to delete is from different table. that's the main issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After so much of discussion with [Quan Nguyen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4896960/quan-nguyen). And with my *team*. Finally I got the solution which worked for me.

The logic was simple but was confused with the relation of the `SQL Query`

Here is the code:-

```
protected void GrdTraining_DeleteCommand(object sender, Obout.Grid.GridRecordEventArgs e)
{
    if (Session["dt10"] != null)
    {
        dt10 = (DataTable)Session["dt10"];
    }
    else
    {
        BindDatatable();
    }
    DataRow[] grdTrain = dt10.Select("SR_NO=" + Convert.ToString(e.Record["SR_NO"]));
    dt10.Rows.Remove(grdTrain[0]);
    AddToViewState("GrdTraining");
    string strempcode = CF.ExecuteScaler("select emp_card_no from emp_mst a, user_mst b where a.mkey=b.employee_mkey and  b.mkey=" + Session["UserId"]);
    CF.ExecuteDT("DELETE FROM EMP_ATTACHED_DOCUMENTS where category_id = 'TC' and pk1_value='" + strempcode + "' and document_id='" + e.Record["SR_NO"] + "'");
}
```